# Does UPDATE check for same values?

Tags: sql-update

Somehow I skipped or forgot this about SQL UPDATE command.

When I do UPDATE on a database row, does UPDATE check for the same values and updates only not-same ones or it simply overwrites all cells in the row?

Note: under UPDATE I mean updating all columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will **Overwrite** the data.

Of course it will overwrite the field, but it doesn't really matter, it's the same value.